# How to make one string based on others two in C?

Tags: c, string

I want to create an program in C, that I have one string , for example "Good Morning" and other one "How are you". So, the program will make one based in these two strings, for example "Good How Morning are you ".

I tried:

```
 char string_1[99];
 char string_2[99];

mix(string_1 + string_2);
```

Comment: I don't think outsourcing your homework to SO is the right way to learn programming.

Comment: @hyde That posting is a simple `strcat()` issues.  Here the combined string is interlaced based on spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This is the algorithm which you can try out:

1. Find the length of combined string and allocate memory.
2. Copy each character of first string until `white space` is reached

   ```
   while(src1[i]!=' ') {
       dest[i] = src[i];
       i++;
   }
   ```
3. Then switch over to other string and copy till white space.
4. Keep alternating between step 2 and 3 til end
5. Append '\0' at end.

Dont forget to handle case when one string has finished. Then you just need to copy the second one as it is.

Comment: How it would be? Can u make it for me? please

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible implementation of your described `mix` method,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define set(ret, b, bPos, start, rPos, bLen) \
            ret[rPos++] = b[bPos++]; \
            if (b[bPos] == ' ' || b[bPos] == '\0') { \
                start = !start; \
                ret[rPos++]=' '; \
                if (bPos < bLen) bPos++; \
            }


char *mix (char *a, char *b);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *string_1 = "Good Morning";
    char *string_2 = "How are you";
    char *out = mix (string_1, string_2);
    printf ("%s\n", out);
    free (out);
}

char * mix (char *a, char *b) {
    bool start = true;
    const size_t aLen = strlen(a);
    const size_t bLen = strlen(b);
    const size_t rLen = 2 + aLen + bLen;
    char *ret = malloc (rLen);
    size_t aPos = 0;
    size_t bPos = 0;
    size_t rPos = 0;
    while (aPos < aLen || bPos < bLen) {
        if (start && aPos < aLen) {
            set(ret, a, aPos, start, rPos, aLen);
        } else if (bPos < bLen) {
            set(ret, b, bPos, start, rPos, bLen);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And the output is

```
Good How Morning are you
```

Comment: +1 Nice. Minor: Suggest not mixing index types of `size_t` or `int`, instead `size_t` aPos = 0; ...`.

Comment: @chux Excellent point. Edited.